# JQuery Tooltip Not Allowing Button to be Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using JQuery tooltip plugin and I'm trying to simulate a input button on hover, which it does successfully but I cannot click on said button. It's like it never exists in the DOM, or maybe it does but then is instantly removed. I'm not sure why the click is not binding.

http://jsfiddle.net/BgDxs/126/

```
$("[title]").bind("mouseleave", function (event) {
        var evt = event ? event : window.event;

        var target = $(evt.srcElement || evt.target);

        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

        var fixed = setTimeout(
            function () {
                target.tooltip("close");
            }, 200);

        $(".ui-tooltip").hover(
                    function () { clearTimeout(fixed); },
                    function () { target.tooltip("close"); }
                );
    });
$("[title]").tooltip({
        content: "...wait...",
        position: { my: "left top", at: "right center" },
        open: function (event, ui) {            
            var _elem = ui.tooltip;

            window.setTimeout(
                function() {                                            
                        var html = "<input type='button' value='Card Information' class='card_info_popup'></input>";

                        _elem.find(".ui-tooltip-content").html(html);
                    },
                200);
        },
        track: false,
        show: 100
    });


$('.card_info_popup').on('click', '.container', function() {
    alert('click');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using event delegation wrongly here since `.container` is not the child of your input with class `card_info_popup`, so you need to use:

```
$('body').on('click', '.card_info_popup', function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

instead of:

```
$('.card_info_popup').on('click', '.container', function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BgDxs/128/)**

Comment: I thought the event needed to be delegated to the parent object?

Comment: @Undermine2k Yes you're correct, delegated events should be bind to the closest static parent. In your case, all the parents div of your tooltip is also dynamically created by `jQuery UI`, so `body` is the closest parent in this case.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
$('.card_info_popup').on('click', '.container', function() {
    alert('click');

});
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.card_info_popup', function() {
    alert('click');    
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BgDxs/127/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

You have to use event delegation to enable the click event on the newly created tooltip button
http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
$(document).on('click', '.card_info_popup', function() {
    alert('click');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to delegate `on('click');` to a static element then bind it to the dynamically generated popup.

I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BgDxs/130/

Here is the updated code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ui-tooltip input.card_info_popup', function() {
    alert('click');
});
```